# Unable to flash TWRP recovery on nvidia shield tablet 6.0.1

Tags: rooting, twrp, nvidia-shield

I have TWRP Recovery file in the same folder as Minimal adb anf fastboot. The '.img' file is not flashing and i'm shown the options as attached in the screenshot of the command prompt. What to do?
P.S. - I'm a beginner.[image]

Comment: What does `fastboot boot <filename>` do?

Comment: It flashes the TWRP file